# How can I execute an Oracle function from within a LINQ expression in Entity Framework 4?

Tags: c#, oracle, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4

I am using Visual Studio 2010, C#, Entity Framework 4 and Oracle 10g.

I need to be able to return the result of a database function as a scalar property of an anonymous type.

My Oracle schema has two tables, PARENT and CHILD, and a function FNC_ADD.  I have created an entity model using the Visual Studio ADO.NET Entity Data Model template, including both tables and the function.

The StorageModels section of my .edmx file looks like this:

```
<!-- SSDL content -->
<edmx:StorageModels>
<Schema Namespace="LINQtest2Model.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="Devart.Data.Oracle" ProviderManifestToken="ORA" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl">
    <EntityContainer Name="LINQtest2ModelStoreContainer">
      <EntitySet Name="CHILD" EntityType="LINQtest2Model.Store.CHILD" store:Type="Tables" Schema="LINQ_TEST" />
      <EntitySet Name="PARENT" EntityType="LINQtest2Model.Store.PARENT" store:Type="Tables" Schema="LINQ_TEST" />
      <AssociationSet Name="LINQ_TEST_FK_PARENT" Association="LINQtest2Model.Store.LINQ_TEST_FK_PARENT">
        <End Role="PARENT" EntitySet="PARENT" />
        <End Role="CHILD" EntitySet="CHILD" />
      </AssociationSet>
    </EntityContainer>
    <EntityType Name="CHILD">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="CHILD_ID" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="CHILD_ID" Type="decimal" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="PARENT_ID" Type="decimal" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="F_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" MaxLength="20" />
      <Property Name="L_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" MaxLength="50" />
      <Property Name="CREATE_DATE" Type="DATE" Nullable="false" />
    </EntityType>
    <EntityType Name="PARENT">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="PARENT_ID" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="PARENT_ID" Type="decimal" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="F_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" MaxLength="20" />
      <Property Name="L_NAME" Type="VARCHAR2" MaxLength="50" />
      <Property Name="CREATE_DATE" Type="DATE" Nullable="false" />
    </EntityType>
    <Association Name="LINQ_TEST_FK_PARENT">
      <End Role="PARENT" Type="LINQtest2Model.Store.PARENT" Multiplicity="1">
        <OnDelete Action="Cascade" />
      </End>
      <End Role="CHILD" Type="LINQtest2Model.Store.CHILD" Multiplicity="*" />
      <ReferentialConstraint>
        <Principal Role="PARENT">
          <PropertyRef Name="PARENT_ID" />
        </Principal>
        <Dependent Role="CHILD">
          <PropertyRef Name="PARENT_ID" />
        </Dependent>
      </ReferentialConstraint>
    </Association>
    <Function Name="FNC_ADD" ReturnType="decimal" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="LINQ_TEST">
      <Parameter Name="V1" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
      <Parameter Name="V2" Type="decimal" Mode="In" />
    </Function>
  </Schema></edmx:StorageModels>
```

I created an extension method to define the function for the entity data model that looks like this:

```
public partial class LINQtest2Entities
{
    [EdmFunction("LINQtest2Model", "FNC_ADD")]
    public decimal FNC_ADD(decimal V1, decimal V2)
    {
        // don’t need to implement the function
        throw new ApplicationException();
    }
}
```

I call the function in a LINQ expression like this:

```
using (var context = new LINQtest2Entities())
{
    var parents = from p in context.PARENTs
                  select new
                  {
                      children = from c in p.Children
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     p.PARENT_ID,
                                     c.CHILD_ID,
                                     a = context.FNC_ADD(p.PARENT_ID, c.CHILD_ID)
                                 }
                  };

    foreach (var parent in parents)
    {
        foreach (var child in parent.children)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("P {0}  C {1}  A {2}", child.PARENT_ID, child.CHILD_ID, child.a);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything compiles correctly, but when I run the code I get this:

`The specified method 'System.Decimal FNC_ADD(System.Decimal, System.Decimal)' on the type 'LINQtest2.LINQtest2Entities' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Was your issue resolved? I know it's an old post, but the solution proposed doesn't work in my application. Although it calls the function but on the statement "foreach (var parent in parents)" it throws the same exception that is thrown in the function i.e. ApplicationException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your namespace arg to `EdmFunctionAttribute` looks suspicious. That looks like a CLR type, not a store space. [This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2008/10/08/edm-and-store-functions-exposed-in-linq.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0) might help you sort that out.

Comment: That blog post gave me exactly what I needed.  The namespaceName should have been LINQtest2Model.Store.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Model.Store namespace:

```
public partial class LINQtest2Entities
{
    [EdmFunction("LINQtest2Model.Store", "FNC_ADD")]
    public decimal FNC_ADD(decimal V1, decimal V2)
    {
        // don’t need to implement the function
        throw new ApplicationException();
    }
}
```

In case you have provided the namespace correctly everything works smoothly.