# How to compare dates (stored as strings) with linq to entities?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to pull data from a database by begin/end date parameters.

However the date that I need to filter on is stored as a string in Oracle DB.

Using linq how can I filter the dates out based on my parameters (which will be in a DateTime type)?

I originally tried:

```
var test = context.MY_TABLE
  .Include(x => x.MY_DETAILS)
  .Where(x => startDate >= MyHelpers.ConvertDate(x.DATE_FIELD) && 
                endDate <= MyHelpers.ConvertDate(x.DATE_FIELD))
  .ToList();
```

I understand the error because linq can't generate the necessary sql statements from my method.

So how can I compare the dates with linq that are stored in the DB as a string?

To boot I won't know how the date will be stored in the string.  
For the time being I will assume '3/10/2016 12:30:00' will be the date string.

Comment: *Don't* load dates as strings. Is that October 3 or March 10 ?

Comment: Storing ambiguous dates as string in a database is going to break badly at some point - don't do this. If you have to store dates as strings in your db (and you don't if you are using Oracle) then store them in ISO format

Comment: I'm well aware of this.  I did not create this DB, I just have to deal with the sins on whoever did create this.

Comment: Have him fix it then. You *really* can't cover this up (is it October or March?) anymore than you can cover up using ANSI instead of Unicode - MAYBE if you hard-code the locale and accept that you'll get occasional bugs when you forget to use the proper locale for parsing. Sometimes the bug will cause a crash (eg `31/12`) sometimes it won't (`12/`12`)

Comment: Guys please downvote questions if they are poorly formatted, broad, out of topic, subjective, possible duplicate, shows lack of effort etc. Dont downvote if you disagree with design choices of OP. OP has a real problem here.

Comment: Another problem is that only format that have the year in the front are sortable. In this case though you only want to do a `between` check, so you can conver the start/end parameters to a string and pass them to EF or the database. The trick would be to find a way to force EF to use a `BETWEEN` clause

Comment: What ORM are you using? EF? NHibernate? LINQ is just the language on top of the ORM. Statements like `BETWEEN` are generated using ORM-specific functionality

Comment: I am using Entity Framework.

Comment: I wonder if you can use the technique in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928748/how-can-i-execute-an-oracle-function-from-within-a-linq-expression-in-entity-fra) to call `TO_DATE` and trhen compare the values?

Comment: `TO_DATE` would force a full table scan but at least it would work. `BETWEEN` wouldn't work even with raw SQL simply because Oracle will order the strings aphabetically. Perhaps add a virtual column to the table? Or create a materialized view with the results of `TO_DATE` ? A materialized view would allow indexing the columns and avoid the full scan. Using it wouldn't require any special techniques either

Comment: @JDS Don't do this on the client app. Solve it on `Oracle` instead and provide the correct data type to the client apps. Add a collumn on oracle where the date is in date format. It can be a computed collumn, or populated with a data migration plus some triggers (YMMV). You may need to adjust your indexes afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How big is the list? On .NET side the easiest way would be parsing the string into `DateTime` method and compare the results. But it is not possible to do that on Database side because EF cannot translate methods like `DateTime.Parse` or your `MyHelpers.ConvertDate`.
If your list is not very large (you must decide what "*large*" exactly means) you can "download all into .NET" and handle the data there. This can be done by calling `ToList` or `ToArray` before the first custom method is called.

```
var test = context.MY_TABLE
                  .Include(x => x.MY_DETAILS)
                  .ToList() // or .ToArray()
                  .Where(x => startDate >= MyHelpers.ConvertDate(x.DATE_FIELD) && 
                           endDate <= MyHelpers.ConvertDate(x.DATE_FIELD))
                  .ToList();
```

But this solution can be slow if you have a large result set and if you don't need the complete data it is pretty wasteful.

Another way I see is, not accessing the `DbSet<T>` but using a stored procedure. This procedure can parse the strings, compare them and return only what you really need.
SPs can be easily accessed in EF like the table data but the select-code is on database side written in SQL.

As mentioned by [RIanGillis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2367188/riangillis) you can use [ExecuteSqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead of a stored procedure too. This method takes an SQL string as an argument, so you can use any conversion method that is available in your database. It works similar to a stored procedure but the SQL statement would be stored in the .NET code.

Comment: That is a *bad* idea. This would load the entire table in memory. 1K rows may sound like a lot for an in-memory list but are essentially 0 for a database. Tables also contain many columns. Locking an entire table and loading several thousand full rows in memory simply to select 5 makes for some very, very unhappy DBAs and customers. Oracle may not *block* but concurrency will still suffer. It gets worse if transactions are used.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I mentioned it already in my answer. But the OP did not say how large his table is. In my projects I have some tables with less than 10 rows so there it would not be a problem in my opinion.

Comment: @JDS And the stored procedure? Or am I missing something other?

Comment: If possible, convert the data in the DB or create a procedure in the DB to convert/ format the date using TO_DATE and access that instead of the table. If the above is not an option you can craft your own query instead of using LINQ to create one and include the TO_DATE conversion with appropriate formatting using ExecuteSqlCommand.

Comment: Yes the SP sounds like a good plan.  This sounds like a viable option.